# PyQt signal slot issue with signal outside creating class

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyqt4

I am trying to create a toolbar that can be modified to change actions on the fly.

However signals are not being sent when I add actions from outside the class that creates the toolbar.

In the example below the new action is never triggered. Any idea on how this can be done?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from toolbarmodifier import ToolbarModifier

class FluidToolbar(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FluidToolbar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        createAction = QtGui.QAction( 'create Action', self)
        createAction.triggered.connect(self.createActions)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('create Action')
        self.toolbar.addAction(createAction)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)  
        self.show()

    def createActions(self):
        print(">>createActions()")
        toolbarModifier = ToolbarModifier()
        toolbarModifier.addAction(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FluidToolbar()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**toolbarmodifier.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget


class ToolbarModifier(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ToolbarModifier, self).__init__()

    def newActionTriggered(self):
        print(">>newActionTriggered()")

    def addAction(self, gui):
        triggerAction = QtGui.QAction( 'New action', gui)
        triggerAction.triggered.connect(self.newActionTriggered)
        gui.toolbar.addAction(triggerAction)
        print("<<addAction()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having a link back to parent was the issue. In FluidToobar modify code in createActions method to include self in call:

```
toolbarModifier = ToolbarModifier(self)
```

In ToolbarModifier change first few lines to:

```
class ToolbarModifier(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolbarModifier, self).__init__(parent)
```